# Как поставить системную иконку файла? Как например в svchost.exe

Tags: pyinstaller, python-3.7

Компилировать я все прекрасно могу. Но мне нужно или убрать иконку каким-то образом на дефолтную,или просто чтобы вы пожалуйста скинули ico файл этой иконки. Пользуюсь такой компиляцией:

```
pyinstaller -F  -i (картинка и название файла)
```